# Sum of the absolute values

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, summation

I was going over a question and need your opinion about solution of the sum of the absolute values as

$$S_n = |0-a|+|1-a|+|2-a|+ \dots + |(n-1)-a|+|n-a|$$

where a is a constant term. What could be the general sum of this series?

Answer (score 0):

The general sum of the series, assuming $a$ is real, is easily expressed in terms of the auxiliary function $s(n,a) := \sum_{k=0}^n (n-a) = (n+1)(\frac n2 - a)$.  Then
$$ S_n = \begin{cases}
s(n,a) - 2s(\lfloor a \rfloor, a), & 0 < a< n; \\
s(n,a), & 0 \ge a; \\
-s(n,a), & a \ge n.
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you clarify how to get or prove that  $S_n = s(n,a) - 2s(\lfloor a \rfloor, a)$. Because in my case $0 < a < n$.

Comment: @Zizu006 The terms $|k-a|$ where $k\le \lfloor a \rfloor$ need to be treated as $a-k$ rather than $k-a$.  We already have a notation to capture the sum of all such terms.  To flip a $+B$ into a $-B$ you subtract $2B$.